# Spring validation set field value

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm currently trying to familiarize myself with spring validation for web pages. Most of the examples I see online show how to send an error message for validation. I am curious as to how to go about setting a value for a field as a part of validation.

Here's an example to better explain myself

Imagine some class for a web page that takes the details of someones salary

**Example of getter and setter**

```
public Integer getSalary() {
    return Salary;
}

public void setSalary(Integer Salary) {
    this.Salary = Salary;
}
```

A persons salary cannot be less than zero so in the event a negative figure is entered the field is to be updated to be a zero.

How can this be done?

Would it be done in the validation class?

**Example section in validation class**

```
if(!isBlank(emp.getSalary)){
    int sal = emp.getSalary;

    if(sal < 0){
        rejectValue("emp.salary", "error.salaryRedection");
        // Do something here?
        // e.g getSalary(setSalary(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the salary before setting to a different method:-

```
public void setSalary(Integer Salary) 
{
    this.Salary = validatedSalary(Salary);
}
```

and you can make the method return the right value  :-

```
public int validatedSalary(int Salary) 
{
    if(Salary < 0)  
    { 
       return 0;
    }
    return Salary;
}
```